# Intersection of growing spheres

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to solve this problem where there are 4 spheres given, with their centers and initial radii:

Bi = (Ci, Wi) where Ci = (xi,yi,zi) is the center of the sphere and Wi is its initial radius.

The radius of the balls increase continuously together by a parameter, say a. That is, as 'a' increases from 0 to infinity, radius of the spheres at any instant is Wi + a. Now, the spheres are : Bi = (Ci, Wi+a). The problem is to find the minimum 'a' for which the (editted) volumes of four spheres intersect together.

Is it possible to solve this problem efficiently instead of writing tedious math equations for all spheres and solving for 'a'?

Comment: The question should be, "is it possible to solve the problem efficiently with some maths instead of tediously performing a numerical approximation on a computer?"

Comment: Note also that the problem may have no solution at all. For example, if all centres are equal and the initial radii distinct, then at any `a` the spheres will be disjoint.

Comment: Doyou mean intersection of the surfaces of the spheres, or the entire volume of the four spheres ?  If the former, then intersection of any two spheres is a circle  (if they intersect at all) So for any division of the four spheres into two pair of spheres, intersection would be intersectioon of those two circles, whic, if they happen to be in different parallel planes, will never intersect at all.  In fact, even if they are  not parallel, the chances of them intersecting is very slim. (The chance of two one dimensional paths intersecting in 3-space is small)

Comment: I meant the intersection of volumes, sorry. I thought it might be analogous to 2D where common intersection of areas of 3 growing circles starts off at a point.

Comment: I have problems understanding your question. Are you saying you are looking for the smallest value of a such that there is at least a single point which is common to all 4 spheres? That is the intersection of all closed balls is not empty?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the smallest value of 'a' such that all the closed balls just touch each other.

Answer (score 4):

Sphere intersections, fortunately, are the simplest of all types of 3-d intersections. If the sum of the radii of two spheres is greater than the distance between their center points, then their volumes intersect.

So the easiest way to solve this is to find the greatest distance between any pair of spheres (find the distance between the centers then subtract their initial radii). Given that distance, divide by 2, and you have the value for a at which all the spheres touch. Any larger than that value, and they will all overlap.

Now, actually, that's not quite the answer to your problem, which is "how large a value of a do I need for all the spheres to form a single coherent volume". After all, if I put the spheres in a row, each one only needs to touch its nearest neighbor for a coherent volume to form. So you still need to solve the connected-graph part of the problem, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also, the greatest distance between any pair of spheres divided by 2 just gives me a value for which all pairs of spheres intersect each other, but they may not intersect at a common volume though. Analogous to the 2D case, where 3 circles may mutually intersect the other two without having a common area intersected by all 3 circles.

Answer (score 1):

Given four spheres L, M, N, O - with initial radius rL, rM, rN, rO and centers cL, cM, cN, cO and common additional radius "a".

L intersects M when

```
Distance(cL, cM) <= rL + rM + 2a
```

With four spheres, there's these possible constraints.

```
  //at least one of
Distance(cL, cM) <= rL + rM + 2a
Distance(cL, cN) <= rL + rN + 2a
Distance(cL, cO) <= rL + rO + 2a
  //and at least one of
Distance(cM, cL) <= rM + rL + 2a
Distance(cM, cN) <= rM + rN + 2a
Distance(cM, cO) <= rM + rO + 2a
  //and at least one of
Distance(cN, cL) <= rN + rL + 2a
Distance(cN, cM) <= rN + rM + 2a
Distance(cN, cO) <= rN + rO + 2a
  //and at least one of
Distance(cO, cL) <= rO + rL + 2a
Distance(cO, cM) <= rO + rM + 2a
Distance(cO, cN) <= rO + rN + 2a
```

But that's "writing tedious math equations for all spheres".

Here's a short (n^2) implementation in c# with Linq.

```
decimal aResult =
(
  from left in spheres
  from right in spheres
  let dist = Distance(left.Center, right.Center)
  let aRaw = (dist - left.startRadius - right.startRadius)/2
  let a = aRaw < 0 ? 0 : aRaw   //spheres might start out touching!
  group a by left into g
  select g.Min()  //the smallest extra radius for each group
).Max();
//the largest extra radius that makes at least one equation true for each group.
// any smaller, and there exists a disconnected sphere with no true equation.
```

It should be possible to prune the matchings using prior calculations to beat n^2.

---

> Analogous to the 2D case, where 3 circles may mutually intersect the other two without having a common area intersected by all 3 circles.

Oh, well that's a different problem.  Hmm.

Suppose you have three oranges arranged in a triangle lying flat on the surface of the earth.  Each sphere touches the other three, yet there is no common point shared by all four spheres.

You want the smallest "a" such that a common point (x, y, z) exists.

```
 //all must be true
(x - cL)^2 + (y - yL)^2 + (z - zL)^2 <= (a + rL)^2
(x - cM)^2 + (y - yM)^2 + (z - zM)^2 <= (a + rM)^2
(x - cN)^2 + (y - yN)^2 + (z - zN)^2 <= (a + rN)^2
(x - cO)^2 + (y - yO)^2 + (z - zO)^2 <= (a + rO)^2
```

Comment: Yes, but solving the above 4 eqns for x,y,z,a might give complicated expressions and is quite tedious. Also computing the result of these four expressions will have lot of precission errors.